# Does Postfix also operate as mail submission agent (MSA)?

Tags: postfix, smtp

I'm just curious whether Postfix also plays a role of MSA in a process of SENDING an e-mail? In other words, does MUA "talk" directly to MTA (say, Roundcube transfers an e-mail to Postfix without any help from MDA such a Dovecot)? Again, I'm asking about **sending** and NOT receiving!

Comment: What do postfix docs say in regards?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Postfix can act as an MSA by enabling the `submission` section of `master.cf` and making changes to the `smtp_` configuration options as desired. This is disabled by default; the tutorial you are following should instruct you to enable it as part of the setup process.

Comment: I haven't touched it. So what happens in a default situation? Does Dovecot act as MSA?

Comment: @papakota If you didn't install something else, then you don't necessarily have an MSA.

Comment: So which service submits the mail to Postfix then when it's about to be sent? MUA does it directly vs. Postfix? Is that so?

Comment: @papakota Yes, your MUA sends the mail to Postfix. For example you might run Thunderbird on your local PC and send a mail. This requires `submission` to be enabled as described above. A process running on the same machine as Postfix (e.g. a web server running Roundcube) can drop a message directly into the mail spool, whether `submission` is enabled or not.